# In theory, does the indexed version of document always take less memory than the actual version of the document?

Tags: search, indexing, inverted-index

For this discussion, we can limit the type of index to inverted index.

E.g. Let's say this particular webpage is crawled by some web-crawler (say Nutch) and then it is indexed into say Solr. The only fields which are crawled are title and body of this question. Now, there is a definite size in memory associated for the text in these two fields. But when they are indexed, they may or may not occupy the same size of memory as the actual content.Is there a possibility that this indexed version of the document takes more memory than the original size of the document or is it implementation specific?

Comment: Huh?  That seems like a very vague question.   Can you provide some context?

Comment: I have added some more details.